# VoiceXML Grammar Event at any given time

Tags: voicexml

Is there any way in VoiceXML to to trigger an event from a grammar no matter what the context? Like a user saying `start over` at any given moment during a call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [VoiceXML Link element](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml1.3.6).  You can specify them at the document level or in the root document to make them global and then catch the matching event:

```
<link event="selection">        
    <grammar mode="voice" src="startovergrammar.srgs"/>
</link>
```